# Disabling port on one dual port NIC interrupts connections to the other dual port NIC

Tags: linux, networking, centos, nic

This is using CentOS 5.5. I have two dual port NICs on a server:

NIC1:
eth0, eth1

NIC2:
eth2, eth3

I have an ssh and vnc session open to the ip address on eth2. When I disable eth0 (ifdown eth0), my sessions  to eth2 disconnect and I no longer receive a response when pinging that ip address. What could be happening?

Comment: eth0 and eth2 are on the same network, so I suspect data is coming in on eth2, but going out of eth0 due to the routing table.

Comment: If they are on the same network, why not create a bond interface?

Answer (score 1):

You can run tcpdump -i eth0 and see if the packets are going out via eth0 instead of eth2.

Comment: This would be my guess as well. you can disable it (so that connection replies go out the interface they originally came in on) with `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth2/rp_filter` and/or add `net.ipv4.conf.eth2.rp_filter = 0` to /etc/sysctl.conf